# How do I get the actual values for left/right/top/bottom of an absolutely positioned element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, position

*(This seems like a simple question that would have been asked before, but if it has I can't find it, though there are lots of similar ones that don't answer what I want.)*

In Firefox (24.0), this code gives me what I want - the relevant number of pixels:

```
jQuery('selector').css('right')
```

In Chrome (34.0.1847.137 m), it only gives pixels for left/top but returns `auto` for right/bottom.

There are various questions on SO explaining that this is the expected behaviour of .css, but I cannot find anything that explains how to get my desired behaviour - i.e. give me calculated pixel values for all four values.

Do JS or jQuery have any way to directly get these four values, that works consistently in all browsers/scenarios? (Or do I have to resort to ugly manual calculations?)

**Clarification:**
I need values that are equivalent to the `.css('right')` values that Firefox returns - which is the distance between the right-edges of the current and parent element. This is not the same as viewport-relative left+width definitions which some functions return.

i.e. the logged values here should be numerically the same:

```
elem = jQuery('selector')
rect = someFunction( elem[0] );
console.log([ elem.css('left') , rect.left ]);
console.log([ elem.css('right') , rect.right ]);
console.log([ elem.css('top') , rect.top ]);
console.log([ elem.css('bottom') , rect.bottom ]);
```

Unless I'm misreading the other answers, only [kalley's getRelativeClientRect answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23891892/how-do-i-get-the-actual-values-for-left-right-top-bottom-of-an-absolutely-positi#23891934) meets this criteria.

Comment: Can't you just add the width and height to the left and top values?

Comment: No, because `.css('right')` is the number of pixels from the parent's right-most edge, which is not the same as left+width.

Comment: Ah OK, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can use [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect). It will take into account any transforms as well, if you are using them.

You'd need to call it like `jQuery('selector')[0].getBoundingClientRect()`. Or use vanilla javascript like `document.querySelector('selector').getBoundingClientRect()`, which will return a single element or `document.querySelectorAll('selector')[index].getBoundingClientRect()`.

To summarize, in a slightly more readable format:

- `jQuery('selector')[0].getBoundingClientRect()`
- `document.querySelector('selector').getBoundingClientRect()`
- `document.querySelectorAll('selector')[index].getBoundingClientRect()`

or replace the QS calls with older ones like `getElementById`, etc.

Here's a function you could use if you wanted to get it relative to it's parent:

```
function getRelativeClientRect(el) {
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect(),
      parentRect = el.offsetParent.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    bottom: parentRect.bottom - rect.bottom,
    height: rect.height,
    left: rect.left - parentRect.left,
    right: parentRect.right - rect.right,
    top: rect.top - parentRect.top,
    width: rect.width
  };
}
```

Comment: Oh, that's neat! I guess my comment on the OP was inaccurate.

Comment: it's worth noting that `getBoundingClientRect` returns some rectangle having `left` and `top` **relative to the viewport**, so it's of course a different thing. Using it also requires the so-called ***ugly manual calculation***.

Comment: Added a function that will normalize everything based on the `offsetParent` of your element. Thanks @KingKing for pointing out the flaws in using that alone.

Comment: left and top were returning negative values (I fixed the order), but I guess this might be the best option for now

Comment: @PeterBoughton  I'm using this function on my site, but encounter some strange problem. While running in an interval, this function seems to return different values when users switch to different browswer tab.
Please take a look at this question of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28842302/webpage-javascript-behaves-differently-when-the-view-is-switched-to-other-browse

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: this is about `absolute position`**

**Very old function findPos**

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html

**Variante considering scroll & borders**

```
function getPosition(el){
 var x=0,y= 0;
 while(el) {
  x+=(el.offsetLeft-el.scrollLeft+el.clientLeft);
  y+=(el.offsetTop-el.scrollTop+el.clientTop);
  el=el.offsetParent;
 }
 return{x:x,y:y}
}
```

to get right

```
  var info=getPosition(element);
  console.log('marginRight: '+info.x-element.offsetWidth);
```

**Note1**: these are vanilla javascript functions that are compatible with older browsers.
thats why jQuery is not needed.obiovsly the performance is much better than using jQuery.

**Note2**: there are many other versions if you search *find position*

**getBoundingClientRect**

to get the right

```
  var info=element.getBoundingClientRect(); // Native Javascript ..think 1.6+
  console.log('marginRight: 'info.right-info.width);
```

**Conclusion**

There is no easy way to get the dimensions,offsets,applied css of an element if you want a allround compatible script.

the `getPosition` function is probably the best function (considering compatibility) that allows you to easely calculate this values..

**Note:** as there is a while loop inside the function, on very old machines you could get some problems with heavely nested elements.

if your using html5 and css than go for `getBoundingClientRect`

**Note:** probably both break when using css3 transforms.

**EDIT**

> I need values that are equivalent to the .css('right') values that
>   Firefox returns

To get those values you first need to find the position of the element.

So:`getPosition` function or `getBoundingClientRect`

then you need to calculate the top/bottom,left/right values.

```
left=x
right=x-width
top=y
bottom=y-height
```

**EDIT2:**

To apply this only to the parent element you need to execute `getPosition` also on the parent element

and the calculations are shown in @kalley's answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in way to do this in Javascript without JQUERY. There are two special ones I'll show you, one is JS and CSS, other is just JS.

```
element.style.left; //Gives you distance from left edge of your viewport.
element.style.top + "px"; //Gives you distance in pixels from top edge
element.style.right; //etc.


//There is also the way of Offset. You do not need CSS at all for this.
//Of course, Jquery has its own way of doing this, but I'll show JS-only
element.offsetTop; //Gives distance from top of viewport to top of element
element.offsetLeft; //Gives distance from left of viewport to left of element
//etc.
```

As always, there are many more ways to do this with and without Jquery. I prefer not using Jquery at all (despite the fact that it is awesome), and I know others prefer not using Jquery too. If you want to use Jquery, I'd recommend using the Jquery way like @farincz did. If not, this way or `getBoundingClientRect` is better. Best thing about using `.style.top` or `.style.left` is that you can not only get the actual values for left/right/top/bottom, but you can also set them. This is great for stuff like drag-and-drop.

Comment: Note that offset can be used to get more accurate left/top/right/bottom values than style, and also note that style (CSS) is most often used to set these values. Style is great for moving the location of an item.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it with $().offset - it returns position in document.
Suppose p be parent element towards which is your element positioned.

then left is

```
var left = $(el).offset().left - $(p).offset().left;
```

right is more complicated, you must use also width

```
var right = ($(p).offset().left + $(p).width()) - ($(el).offset().left + $(el).width());
```

last thing is obtain p elment. You know it directly or find it in $(el).parents()
It has position relative or absolute.

Comment: If I was going to calculate it, this is a step back from just using `.getBoundingClientRect()` which already provides bottom/right, but is relative to the viewport. (And I want equivalent to `.css('right')` which is measured from container's right edge.)

Answer (score 0):

Use function **getBoundingClientRect()**, it gives you left, right, top, bottom, width, height values:

```
var myid=document.getElementById("id").getBoundingClientRect();
var bottom=myid.bottom;
var top=myid.top;
var right=myid.right
```

...
and so on.

Source: [MDN | Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect)

**EDITED:**

To get coordinates with respect to the page and not viewport:

```
var bodycoord=document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
    var top-from-page=myid.top-bodycoord.top;
    var left-from-page=myid.left-bodycoord.top;
```

Comment: The values it gives are not the same - see [King King's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23891892/how-do-i-get-the-actual-values-for-left-right-top-bottom-of-an-absolutely-positi#comment36783584_23891934) to the existing suggestion of this method.