# Webpage javascript behaves differently when the view is switched to other browser tab

Tags: jquery, html, css

Sorry for my English when composing the title, I've tried my best.

Live site: http://tt.fbcwinterretreat.org/
Please be noted to better understand what is going on, I recommend you reduce the window height.

The problem is: If you keep looking at the page, the carousel goes well, but if you switch to another browser tab, wait for a few seconds, and then switch back, you will see the carousel gets displaced. The longer you stay at other browser tab, the more it is displaced.

It seems the problem is coming from this function:

```
function getRelativeClientRect(el) {
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect(),
      parentRect = el.offsetParent.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    bottom: parentRect.bottom - rect.bottom,
    height: rect.height,
    left: rect.left - parentRect.left,
    right: parentRect.right - rect.right,
    top: rect.top - parentRect.top,
    width: rect.width
  };
}
```

which I got from this SO question: [How do I get the actual values for left/right/top/bottom of an absolutely positioned element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23891892/how-do-i-get-the-actual-values-for-left-right-top-bottom-of-an-absolutely-positi).

The following are the HTML and codes of my site:
HTML:

```
<div class='marquee-container'>
    <div class="image-container">
        <div class="image" style="background-image:url('images/1.jpg')"></div>
        <div class="image" style="background-image:url('images/2.jpg')"></div>
        <div class="image" style="background-image:url('images/3.jpg')"></div>
        <div class="image" style="background-image:url('images/4.jpg')"></div>
        <div class="image" style="background-image:url('images/5.jpg')"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.marquee-container{position:relative;overflow:hidden}
.image-container{position:absolute;transition:all 1s ease;  display: -webkit-box;display: -moz-box;display: -ms-flexbox;display: -webkit-flex;display: flex;}
.image{float:left;background-size:cover;cursor:pointer}
```

JS:There are two related JS scripts,the first one is located before closing body tag, I use it to make the images auto fit the height of screen

```
<script>
        (function(){
            var width, height = true;

            function initHeader() {
            headerHeight = document.getElementById('rt-header')? document.getElementById('rt-header').getHeight():0;
                width = window.innerWidth;
                height = window.innerHeight - headerHeight;
                largeHeader = document.getElementById('rt-topfullwidth');
                largeHeader.style.height = height+'px';

                j('.marquee-container').height(height);
                j('.marquee-container .image').height(height);

            }

            // Main
            initHeader();
        })();
    </script>
```

The seconde one is located at http://tt.fbcwinterretreat.org/templates/rt_chimera/js/custom.js, I use it to implement the carousel effect. I know its readability is low, so I have added some comments to it.